# How do you RESTfully get a complicated subset of records?

Tags: algorithm, web-services, rest

I have a question about getting 'random' chunks of available content from a RESTful service, without duplicating what the client has already cached. How can I do this in a RESTful way?

I'm serving up a very large number of items (little articles with text and urls). Let's pretend it's:
/api/article/

My (software) clients want to get random chunks of what's available. There's too many to load them all onto the client. They do not have a natural order, so it's not a situation where they can just ask for the latest. Instead, there are around 6-10 attributes that the client may give to 'hint' what type of articles they'd like to see (e.g. popular, recent, trending...).

Over time the clients get more and more content, but at the server I have no idea what they have already, and because they're sent randomly, I can't just pass in the 'most recent' one they have.

I could conceivably send up the GUIDS of what's stored locally. The clients only store 50-100 locally. That's small enough to stuff into a POST variable, but not into the GET query string.

What's a clean way to design this?

Key points:

- Data has no logical order
- Clients must cache the content locally
- Each item has a GUID
- Want to avoid pulling down duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never be able to make this work satisfactorily if the data is truly kept in a random order (bear in mind the [Dilbert RNG Effect](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator)); you need to fix the order for a particular client so that they can page through it properly. That's easy to do though; just make that particular ordering be a resource itself; at that point, you've got a natural (if possibly synthetic) ordering and can use normal paging techniques.

The main thing to watch out for is that you'll be creating a resource in response to a GET when you do the initial query: you probably should use a resource name that is a hash of the query parameters (including the client's identity if that matters) so that if someone does the same query twice in a row, they'll get the same resource (so preserving proper idempotency). You can always delete the resource after some timeout rather than requiring manual disposal…